# Any clean way to get OpenMP pragmas to work with macros?

Tags: c, c++11, macros, openmp

I have to add OpenMP to a customer's code.  It has a couple of macros that work sort of like so:

```
int i, imax;
#ifdef MAC1
double x1, y1
#endif
#ifdef MAC2
double x2, y2
#endif

//first loop:
for (i=0; i<imax; i++ ) {
#ifdef MAC1
//process x1, y1
#endif
#ifdef MAC2
//process x2, y2
#endif
//do a ton of other stuff
}

// Lots more code.  No way it will all work in one omp region.

//second loop:
for (i=0; i<imax; i++ ) {
#ifdef MAC1
//process x1, y1
#endif
#ifdef MAC2
//process x2, y2
#endif
//do a ton of other stuff
}
```

It is completely possible that `MAC1` and `MAC2` may both be defined, or either, or neither.

So now, I want to run the loops under OpenMP.  This generally won't work:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(x1, y1,   \
                             x2, y2,   \
                             and a     \
                             ton of    \
                             other stuff)
{
...
}
```

... because if `MAC1` and/or `MAC2` are undefined, the compiler complains that `x1, y1`, and/or `x2, y2` are undefined.

I have thought of several ways to get around this that either won't work or are sub-standard:

1) I can't just pull the definitions of these variables into the omp parallel region because, as I said, I will have to use them in a second region later and I can't redefine them there.

2) I guess I could pull these variables outside of their macro blocks and define them whether they are needed or not.  This would be the simplest solution, but that seems kind of "hack-ish".  And I suspect that in principle there are situations where this wouldn't work anyway.

3) I guess I could write several omp pragmas, one for each combination of macros, encased in four different `#ifdefs`, but then I need four different optional pragmas and the code is going to get messy real fast.

4) I tried to do something like

```
#pragma omp parallel private(the other stuff) \
#ifdef MAC1
                     private(x1, y1)   \
#endif
#ifdef MAC2
                     private(x2, y2)   \
#endif
{ ... }
```

This would still be not so nice to look at, but it would be much better than four different optional pragmas.  Nevertheless, I tried several syntax variations of this but the compiler had no idea what I was trying to do.

Anyone know a clean way to do what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Could you `#define macx` and `#define macy` and use those in the function calls?

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks very much for your help.  I'm not sure what you mean.  Probably because I'm kind of new at this.  Could you elaborate?  Much obliged!

Comment: As expanded in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest and most natural thing I can think of would be this:

```
// Just once, in a header if need be:

#ifdef MAC1
// Note trailing comma:
#define MAC1_VARS x1, y1,
#else
#define MAC1_VARS
#endif

#ifdef MAC2
// Note trailing comma:
#define MAC2_VARS x2, y2,
#else
#define MAC2_VARS
#endif
/////////////////////////

// ...

// each parallel region / loop:
#pragma omp parallel private(MAC1_VARS \
                         MAC2_VARS     \
                         other, stuff)
{
    // ...
}
```

The `MAC1_VARS` and `MAC2_VARS` thus expand appropriately, either to nothing or to an appropriate subsequence of the variable list.

If you can modify the client code that conditionally declares those variables, then I would put the definitions of `MAC1_VARS` and `MAC2_VARS` there, too, instead of in separate preprocessor conditionals.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile using C99 and up, you can use the pragma operator: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html

Here's a small working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define MAC1
#define MAC2

#ifdef MAC1
double x1 = 0.0, y1 = 0.1;
#endif

#ifdef MAC2
double x2 = 1.0, y2 = 1.1;
#endif

#if defined(MAC1) && defined(MAC2)
# define MY_OMP_LOOP_PRAGMA _Pragma("omp parallel for firstprivate(x1, y1, x2, y2)")
#elif defined(MAC1)
# define MY_OMP_LOOP_PRAGMA _Pragma("omp parallel for firstprivate(x1, y1)")
#elif defined(MAC2)
# define MY_OMP_LOOP_PRAGMA _Pragma("omp parallel for firstprivate(x2, y2)")
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int imax = 10;
MY_OMP_LOOP_PRAGMA
   for (int i=0; i < imax; ++i) {
#ifdef MAC1
     printf("%d: %f, %f\n", omp_get_thread_num(), x1, y1);
#endif
#ifdef MAC2
    printf("%d: %f, %f\n", omp_get_thread_num(), x2, y2);
#endif
}

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  I've never seen this before.  Thanks!